# datagridview not update in new table

Tags: c#

hello guys i have a problem in the save of information of the absence
 in the form of  absence i had added  a datagridview and in there i add tow columns  combobox form one for the start time of absence and the other for end time 
in the datagridview when i click in the bottom  of "show" it will  add  the name and the ID of each student  from a table named "Etudiant" and there are a datetimepicker in the corner out of the datagridview  so i need when the user choose the time of absence and the date  of each student  and he click in the bottom "save"  it have to be saved in an other table  called  "Absence" and this is my try and there are an error please help mee it's the baccalaureate Project :)

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { // Open the connection using the connection string.
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-6Q836P8JQ1C\oby;Initial Catalog=Etudiant;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Abscence (CIN,Heure_debut,Heure_fin,Date)";
        sqlQuery += "VALUES ('CIN', 'Heure_debut', 'Heure_fin', 'Date')";
            // Insert into the Sql table. ExecuteNonQuery is best for inserts.
            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("CIN", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CIN"].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Heure_debut", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Heure_fin",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column2"].Value);
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("Date", dateTimePicker1.Text);   
                }
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                com.Parameters.Clear();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are errors isn't quite clear, please explain them.

Comment: when i start the program it show an error  "The parameterized query '(@CIN int , @Heure_debut nvarchar(4000),@heure_fin nvarchar(4000),' expects the parameter '@Heure_debut',which was not supplied . "

Comment: I guess you have answered your own question.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the values you are entering are going into the insert's.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ // Open the connection using the connection string.
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-6Q836P8JQ1C\oby;Initial Catalog=Etudiant;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    string sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Abscence (CIN,Heure_debut,Heure_fin,Date)";
    sqlQuery += "VALUES (@CIN, @Heure_debut, @Heure_fin, @Date)";

        // Insert into the Sql table. ExecuteNonQuery is best for inserts.
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, con))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CIN", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["CIN"].Value);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heure_debut", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column1"].Value);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Heure_fin",dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["column2"].Value);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dateTimePicker1.TextToString("YYYY-mm-DD");   
            }
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Parameters.Clear();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: another  problem  "Additional information: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: add this for the parameter dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString("YYYY-mm-DD")).please mark as answer if it helps

Comment: Additional information: The parameterized query '(@CIN int,@Heure_debut nvarchar(4000),@Heure_fin nvarchar(4000),' expects the parameter '@Heure_debut', which was not supplied.

Comment: TextToString("YYYY-mm-DD") there are an  error  here

Comment: if it really helped you.You have missed the @ which needs to be added for SQL's version of variables. Please read this http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/268104-parameterizing-your-sql-queries-the-right-way-to-query-a-database/.

Comment: By the way, adding parameters inside the loop without clearing them seems to be pretty bad to me

Comment: you are right steve   and   user2526236  that's not help

Comment: @oussamabenabdallah I don't know what you need. Appreciate once's effort to correct your code.

Comment: this time  the problem was "Must declare the scalar variable "@CIN"."  how can i declare it ?